# Starting a timer once gameobject is destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to start a timer once a gameobject is destroyed, anyone has ideas on doing it? A scenario would be if a cube is destroyed, the timer then commences

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific in what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnDestroy()` here

```cs
private void OnDestroy()
{
    gameManager.isStartTimer = true;
}
```

and in gameManger class Timer:

```cs
bool isStartTimer;
int timer;

private void Update()
{
   if(isStartTimer)
   {
       timer += Time.deltaTime;
       Debug.Log(timer);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is fine except you want individual timers for individual objects

Comment: @derHugo yes that's what I'm thinking but it depends on the OP.

Comment: Exactly that's why we wait with answers until we have enough information about the actual issue ;)

Comment: you could add both options to your answer to help him find what he wants ;)